# Reliability tests for classic content analysis (multiple categorial codes per item)

Tags: r

In classic content analysis (or qualitative content analysis), as typically done with Atlas.TI or Nvivo type tools (sometimes called QACDAS tools), you typically face the situation of having multiple raters rate many objects with many codes, so there are multiple codes that each rater might apply to each object. I *think* this is what the excellent [John Ubersax page on agreement statistics](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/raw.htm#polyto) calls "Two Raters, Polytomous Ratings".

For example you might have two raters read articles and code them with some group of topic codes from a coding scheme (e.g., diy, shelving, circular saw), and you are asking how well the coders agree on applying the codes.

What I'd like is to use the irr package functions, agree and kappa2, in these situations.  Yet their documentation didn't help me figure out how to proceed, since they expect input in the form of "n*m matrix or dataframe, n subjects m raters." which implies that there is a single rating per rater, per object.

Given two raters using (up to) three codes to code two articles input data that looks like this (two diy articles, the second with some topic tags):

```
article,rater,code
article1,rater1,diy
article1,rater2,diy
article2,rater1,diy
article2,rater2,diy
article2,rater1,circular-saw
article2,rater1,shelving
article2,rater2,shelving
```

I'd like to get:

- Overall percentage agreement.
- Percentage agreement for each code.
- Contingency table for each code.

Ideally, I'd also like to get Positive agreement (how often do the raters agree that a code should be present?) and Negative Agreement (how often do the raters agree that a code should not be present).  See discussion of these at http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/raw.htm#binspe

I'm pretty sure that this involves breaking the input data.frame up and processing it code by code, using something like dplyr, but I wondered if others have tackled this problem.

(The kappa functions take the same input, so let's just keep this simple by using the agree function from the irr package, plus the positive and negative agreement only really make sense with percentage agreement).

Comment: I paraphrase : Do it for me.

Comment: Hi @agstudy, I'm new here. I don't understand why you felt the way I asked the question was lazy, but I wonder, could you help me understand better?  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the meta.stackexchange threads on answering one's own question, it seems that is an acceptable thing to do.  Makes sense, good place to store stuff for others to find :)

I solved most of this with the following code:

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr); library(reshape2); library(irr)

# The irr package expects input in the form of n x m (objects in rows, raters in columns)
# for multiple coders per coded items that is really confusing. Here we have 10 articles (to be coded) and
# many codes.  So each rater rates each combinations of articles and codes as present (or not).

# Basically you send only the ratings columns to agree and kappa2.  You can send them all at 
# once for overall agreement, or send only those for each code for code-by-code agreement.

# letter,code,rater
# letter1,code1,rater1
# letter1,code2,rater1
# letter2,code3,rater2
coding <- read.csv("CombinedCoding.csv")

# Now want:
# letter, code, rater1, rater2
# where 0 = no (this code wasn't used), 1 = yes (this code was used)
# dcast can do this, collapsing across a group. In this case we're not really 
# grouping, so if the code was not present length gives a 0, if it was length 
# gives a 1.
# This excludes all the times where we agreed that both codes weren't present.
ccoding <- dcast(coding, letter + code ~ coder, length)

# create data.frame from combination of letters and codes
# this handles the negative agreement parts.
codelist <- unique(coding$code)
letterlist <- unique(coding$letter)
coding_with_negatives <- merge(codelist, letterlist) # Gets cartesion product of these.
names(coding_with_negatives) <- c("code", "letter") # align the names

# merge this with the coding, produces NA for rows that don't exist in ccoding
coding_with_negatives <- merge(coding_with_negatives,ccoding,by=c("letter","code"), all.x=T)
# replace NAs with zeros.
coding_with_negatives[is.na(coding_with_negatives)] <- 0

# Now want agreement per code.
# need a function that returns a df
# this function gets given the split data frame (ie this happens once per code)
getagree <- function(df) {
    # for positive agreement remove the cases where we both coded it negative
    positive_df <- filter(df, (rater1 == 1 & rater2 == 1) | (rater1 == 0 & rater2 == 1) | (rater1 == 1 & rater2 == 0))

    # for negative agreement remove the cases where we both coded it positive
    negative_df <- filter(df, (rater1 == 0 & rater2 == 0) | (rater1 == 0 & rater2 == 1) | (rater1 == 1 & rater2 == 0))

    data.frame( positive_agree = round(agree(positive_df[,3:4])$value,2)  # Run agree on the raters columns, get the $value, and round it.
      , negative_agree = round(agree(negative_df[,3:4])$value,2)
      , agree = round(agree(df[,3:4])$value,2)
      , used_in_articles = nrow(positive_df) # gives some idea of the prevalance.
    )              
}

# split the df up by code, run getagree on the sections
# recombine into a data frame.
results <- ddply(coding_with_negatives, .(code), getagree)
```

The confusion matrices can be gotten with:

```
print(table(coding_with_negatives[,3],coding_with_negatives[,4],dnn=c("rater1","rater2")))
```

I haven't done it but I think I could do that per code inside the function using print to push them into a text file.